# Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can not figure out what I am missing here. This works fine on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8yA3spgK5YJTDoQAUAlAFzKnIC%20AWABQoSLEQoAgtRHJkMYFExgeK5iADmAbjnICcFWrAade4ABMeIOgFtWUXcKGjw0eEmQAhaskvW7B20BETF3SWQAYVlheSgAeyJjUyd5EDhbCGTQM1jkBAJgCHBsrScXMIlPACU4EAt4218XEQLDTGQARTpoAE8vOmACC2hiVDowAFk4UGQAXmp%20Sio9AEceqF7SKDrMRDBgeJAxifnkePQAKwgEMAAaZABJEDOL69vyNgA6H-RB4egmB43T6AyGIygxGe5AA2gBdbhoLC4fBEE5gZZ6OIQMB0KAvKj8ZCGJHYKB4QgkcYY1IhZwiVoGTAdEGbMEAqAAZVwwE8Kzy6z6212%200Ox2pryuN3uTxeCze0s%20Py%20f3BgOBG36-whUJAsIRMXk2Nx%20OQIAgAHcupr2RDOF9BZthSA9rcxeiHtDvr9tYCOLSXC1hAgjipzuazuaraytWrIVJPv7WqGwMgwBb4pHLdbQb7IV5E04Qy7U2AABZQCAoBZRnNsvPESKFhnCWsx23Qbnk3nsDgOzXO10HI7EWr1RqfI4QB7p%20IzitV-1AA), but not in my code. I have query build that builds graphql queries, but for some reason, I get an error that `Argument of type 'QueryBuilder<CSVManager>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryBuilder<object>'.` Why is this not working?

```js
export interface UserInfoDatabaseResult {
  managers: CSVManager[];
  users: CSVExistingUser[];
  roles: CSVClientRole[];
}

@Injectable()
export class AddMultipleUsersService {

  constructor(
    private readonly queryBuilder: QueryBuilderService
  ) { }

  getUsersInfo(managers: UserId[], users: UserId[], roles: [client: string, role: string][]) {
    const managersQuery = this.getManagers(managers); // QueryBuilder<CSVManager>
    const usersQuery = this.getExistingUsers(users);  // QueryBuilder<CSVExistingUser>
    const rolesQuery = this.getRoles(roles);          // QueryBuilder<CSVClientRole>

    return this.queryBuilder
      .queryTransaction<UserInfoDatabaseResult>(managersQuery, usersQuery, rolesQuery);
  }

  // This simplest one looks like this:
  getExistingUsers(users: UserId[]): QueryBuilder<CSVExistingUser> {
    return this.queryBuilder
      .table<CSVExistingUser>('user_tbl', 'users')
      .select('id: user_id')
      .where({ user_id: { _in: users } });
  }
}
```

Here is how it is called:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class QueryBuilderService {
  public queryTransaction<Out = object, In = object>(...builders: QueryBuilder<In>[]): Observable<Out> {
    return this.connection('default')
      .queryTransaction<Out, In>(...builders);
  }
}
```

This is then the error that I am receiving:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'QueryBuilder<CSVManager>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryBuilder<object>'.
      The types of 'paginationBehavior.observers' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'Observer<IPaginationResult<CSVManager>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<IPaginationResult<object>>[]'.
          Type 'Observer<IPaginationResult<CSVManager>>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<IPaginationResult<object>>'.
            Type 'IPaginationResult<object>' is not assignable to type 'IPaginationResult<CSVManager>'.
    
    42       .queryTransaction<UserInfoDatabaseResult>(managersQuery, usersQuery, rolesQuery);
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As seen in the below image, the second parameter is `unknown` for some reason....

[image: Unknown Parameter]

### Edit

After some investigation, the issue is with this property:

```js
export class QueryBuilder<OutMain extends object = object> {
  private readonly paginationBehavior = new Subject<IPaginationResult<OutMain>>();
}
```

Changing it to the following removes the error, however it is not strongly typed due to the `any` keyword (which I don't want to use). Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
  private readonly paginationBehavior: Subject<IPaginationResult<OutMain>> & {observers: any} = new Subject<IPaginationResult<OutMain>>();
```

Comment: The object/response you are getting from the api is not of type 'CSVManager'

Comment: If it works on some other environment, I would take a look into differences in TypeScript versions and tsconfig

Comment: @IAfanasov I am using the same versions of TypeScript (v4.1.5)

Comment: so your tsconfig. Also your playground code isn't the same as your example above. You're making this really hard for people to help you. Please simplify by replacing your example code with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that fails for you with your current environment and tsconfig, but works in Playground.

Comment: @Inigo I have made an edit to the question. The reason the two work differently, is because I am using a library in my code, and not in the shared playground link.

Comment: sure but you say "This works fine on the typescript playground, but not in my code" and have different code in playground. I point back to my MRE ask. If the Playground code ***as-is*** does not work in your local environment, just use that code in the question, and point out the error and source line ***that*** code produces. And post your tsconfig. Please.